# Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar-choice, syntax

I'm in university and in creative writing they asked us to write a short story. I chose a mystery story and composed this sentence for it:

> Omni usurpant optimes sapientes virtutes acceptum verum vitam.

I tried hard to make it look like the decoded message from the Shugborough statue. I know it is not syntactically correct, but does it make any sense? And what should I change to make it grammatically better?

Comment: 'The best wise works usurp the true taking of life for everyone.' That's the best sense I can make out of it, although even then it's shaky. What did you mean to say?

Comment: This question is unlikely to be salvaged, as it is unclear what the OP wanted to say, and s/he is evidently not coming back. Hence my request to be closed.

Comment: Can you please add the intended original meaning to your question? I have put the question on hold, but it can be reopened it if you edit to clarify.